# Is static data member typed its container type possible in C++?

Tags: c++, static, types, member

I was used something like this in C# or other languages.

```
// C#, but I can't remember correctly. Just assume like a pseudo code.
class A
{
    public int b;
    public A(int newB)
    {
        b = newB
    }
    public static const A a1 = A(1);
    public static const A a2 = A(2);
    public static const A a3 = A(3);
}
```

Is there equivalent of this in C++? Or any recommended way to do this? I do this for just to organize `a1`, `a2`, `a3` within its class name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there equivalent of this in C++?

The following C++ code is equivalent to your C# code:

```
class A
{
    public:
    int b;
    A(int newB) : b(newB)
    {
    }

    //declaration
    static const A a1;
    static const A a2;
    static const A a3;
};

//definition - necessary!
const A A::a1 = A(1);
const A A::a2 = A(2);
const A A::a3 = A(3);
```

Comment: Damn restriction of only allowing static const integrals to be defined inside the class/struct. :)

Comment: The definition doesn’t contain the `static` qualifier.

Comment: @Konrad: Correct.It was copy paste. Edited it!

Comment: How do you think about the case of `A` is defined as `union` instead of `class`?

Comment: @Eonil: According to the Standard, even union is a class. So I think it would be same!